# Button Icon float right not working

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, glyphicons

I have button which has icon in it. I am trying to display text on the left and icon on the right using CSS float: right; but icon and text is still shown centered.

Here is HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/button/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <div>
                    <h4>Basic Button</h4>
                    <p>
    
       
       <button id="primaryTextButton" class="k-button" title="Example of tool tip!" >Primary Button
       <span class="k-icon k-i-info">
       </button>
       </span>

                        
                    </p>
                </div>             
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                   
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                .demo-section p {
                    margin: 0 0 30px;
                    line-height: 50px;
                }
                .demo-section p .k-button {
                    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
                }
                .k-primary {
                    min-width: 150px;
                }
    .k-button {
    min-width: 400px;      
    }
    
    .k-icon{
     padding: 10px;
     font-size: 32px;     
    }
            </style>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am missing here? What do you I need to change to the the icon show on the right?

Comment: Move the `span` below the text "Example"

Comment: Please post minimal code to replicate the issue, not screenshots of code.

Comment: @BenM style gets generated using KendoUI JS so can't really post full code.

Comment: Updated question with working example

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping a `div` around your `button` and apply `overflow: auto` to it.

```
    <div style="overflow: auto;"><button id="reportBtn_33301" type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext" title=" data-role="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
<span class="k-icon k-i-info"></span>
Example
</button></div>
```

Comment: @Farukh Hmm, try adding `position: absolute` to the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="k-icon k-i-info"></span>
```

'span' tag default display property is inline element.

1. You need to change it to display inline-block to work. Then the float will work
2. Change it to display block with some small width, so that it fits in button, then try giving float property to it.

Read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: span added automatically by Kendo UI so can't (or don't know how to) really change that.

Comment: 1. try making the button `position : relative` and `position: absolute` for the icon and then play with top and left property. 
2. Paste span after the text example, this should work

Comment: added example HTML